# Why does voltage spike when resonance frequency is matched with crystal oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, crystal, function-generator, piezoelectricity, piezoelectric-effect

I am learning to test the accuracy of specific frequencies of crystal oscillators using a function generator and oscilloscope. When you get closer the the actual frequency of the crystal the voltage should increase several times when its resonance frequency is matched.

For example, I have a 3.579545MHz crystal oscillator hooked up to a function generator and oscilloscope. I'm using a 5V sine wave on the function generator. As I get the frequency on the function generator very close to the frequency of the crystal, I can see the voltage spike on the oscilloscope to 92V pk-pk around 3.579371MHz.

My question is why does this occur? Is this a phenomenon of the piezoelectric effect on crystals? Any explanation to why we should expect a voltage increase is helpful.

Comment: How is the crystal and other equipment connected to see this? Is there any other components like crystal load capacitors connected? How is the scope and the probes set up?

Comment: You need to use a much lower voltage to drive the tester else the crystal will become damaged with that much resulting voltage at resonance. You must show your test set-up circuit too.

Comment: Also you likely are unable to measure the frequency that reads on the crystal. The crystal has two closely spaced resonance points, the series resonance point where impedance is minimum and the parallel resonance point where the impedance is maximum. Crystals, very often, are used in a Pierce oscillator circuit which is tuned with the rated capacitive loading of the crystal to oscillate at the rated frequency written on the crystal which is between the two resonance frequencies.